# Best way to handle async actions from container components

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I have two async actions that I have to be sure that they were executed correctly before to continue with the next block of code.

The code looks like this:

```
createUser = () => {
    let user = this.state.user
    //create user session (this is a async action - thunk)
    //What is the correct way to wait until this method is executed?
    this.props.createSession(user)
    //if session exists means it was created
    if(this.props.session.session) {
      //What is the correct way to wait until this method is executed?
      this.props.createUser(user) //another async action
      if(this.props.userReducer.currentUser) {
        ToastAndroid.show('User registered successfully!', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
        this.props.goTo('productsContainer') //transition to the next scene
      }
    } else {
      ToastAndroid.show(this.props.session.err, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
}
```

Because the method createSession() and createUser() are async actions I'm a little bit lost about how to "wait" until the first one and the second one are executed.

Maybe it is a dumb question but I'm a newbie at the react-redux world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the actions are async, they return promises. So, wait on the promises:

```
createUser = () => {
    let user = this.state.user
    //create user session (this is a async action - thunk)
    //What is the correct way to wait until this method is executed?
    this.props.createSession(user)
        .then(() => {
            //if session exists means it was created
            if(this.props.session.session) {
              //What is the correct way to wait until this method is executed?
              this.props.createUser(user) //another async action
              if(this.props.userReducer.currentUser) {
                ToastAndroid.show('User registered successfully!', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                this.props.goTo('productsContainer') //transition to the next scene
              }
            } else {
              ToastAndroid.show(this.props.session.err, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
            }
        })
}
```

And so on.

If you're using Babel or TypeScript, you can also use the async/await syntax:

```
createUser = async function() {
    let user = this.state.user
    //create user session (this is a async action - thunk)
    //What is the correct way to wait until this method is executed?
    await this.props.createSession(user)
    //if session exists means it was created
    if(this.props.session.session) {
      //What is the correct way to wait until this method is executed?
      await this.props.createUser(user) //another async action
      if(this.props.userReducer.currentUser) {
        ToastAndroid.show('User registered successfully!', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
        this.props.goTo('productsContainer') //transition to the next scene
      }
    } else {
      ToastAndroid.show(this.props.session.err, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
}.bind(this)
```

Given, however that the entire method works only through data passed in `props` (with the exception of `state.user`), which seem to come from the store anyway, it makes more sense to turn the whole method into an action:

```
createUser = () => props.createSessionAndUser(this.state.user)
...
// implement entire logic in createSessionAndUser action
```